# Add Data text on top of Bars (vertical) - Highcharts Bar charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bar-chart

I am working with Highcharts Bar Graph (vertical) and I would like to have the Members data to appear on top of each bar (hovers we will keep as well which is working). I've tried various ways with plotOptions and could not get this to work to show Members data on top of the bar graph view. The first link is my working code.

```
    **https://codepen.io/jenfloods/pen/jOyXEQd**
```

The second link above is the example is how I would like the data text to appear on top of a bar graph with white shadow letters but this would apply to my vertical bars and not horizontal as this example shows.

```
**https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/bar-datalabels-align-inside-bar/**
```

Anyone has an example or can work with my code to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable data labels for series and use the configuration like below:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    ...,
    dataLabels: {
      rotation: 90,
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 10,
      align: 'left',
      inside: true,
      enabled: true,
      color: '#FFFFFF'
    },
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y04j6z3m/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.dataLabels